# Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a01a8'

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

I'm typically a java developer but was asked to "tweak" a small ASP app my organization has. It basically accepts user input into a form and then emails the data. In my sendmail.asp file I set a session attribute (`Session("emailText") = message`) and then redirect to page printResults.asp.

That page is basically an HTML page with a single line of VBScript code at line 21: `<%Response.Write(Session.Contents("emailText")) %>` .

This all works on my local IIS server but when I deployed it to the host server to test & demo it I got this error:

```
Microsoft VBScript runtime 
error '800a01a8' 
Object required: '' 
/sub3/printResults.asp, line 21
```

Since I am new to ASP I have no clue why this would work locally but not on the host server. Any ideas or suggestions would be most helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that Session State has been disabled either in IIS or elsewhere in code?

When you redirect to printResults.asp are you staying in the same domain and sub-domain (session state will not be maintained between domain/sub-domains) and not switching between HTTP/HTTPS (sessions may have been set to HTTP only)?

Comment: Yeah I was able to determine the problem was with the session state in IIS.  When I disabled session state on my local version I was able to re-create the problem.  I'm not sure why we have session state disabled but that's another issue.  Once I figured that out I was able to find another solution and solve the problem.